# iOS - make Apple TV always present in landscape orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, apple-tv

I am building an iOS app that only presents in portrait orientation on the iPhone. (The views do not change when a user rotates the device.)

However, when users connect to an Apple TV, I want to make the views always present in landscape orientation on Apple TV even the iPhone presents in portrait orientation.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read your question wrong the first time. Have you considered an option such as this: "Some video-oriented apps send their content directly to the AirPlay receiver when AirPlay is enabled—bypassing the iOS device’s screen (or displaying a message like “The video is playing on Apple TV”)". So in theory you might just be able to bypass the iphone and just deal with the apple TV settings.

Comment: thanks, it seems a nice solution. Can you give me more information? like where you get the quote?

Comment: Yes, it is from this link http://www.takecontrolbooks.com/resources/0170/site/chap27.html

it appears in the third green box from the bottom. I believe that the excerpt is from part of a book, which you can purchase for only $10 if interested. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Kleigh, but it seems the article is for normal users. It didn't discuss how to "bypassing the iOS device’s screen" in a technical way.